# Text value in selenium

Tags: css, selenium

I want to get the location of CSS selector whoes text value is present.In my Code its given as 'Parent'.Then how to find out this CSS Selector? And store this value in WebElement.

```css
<div class="aw-relations-innerContainer">
  <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 377.5 297.5)" id="mainCanvas">
    <g data-sdf-index="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="" class="aw-relations-nodeSvg aw-relations-detailLevel0">
      <g data-sdf-index="10" transform="translate(65 11)">
        <g data-sdf-index="11" id="header">
          <g data-sdf-index="12" transform="translate(0 2)" class="">
            <text transform="translate(0)" data-sdf-index="14" id="title" class="aw-widgets-cellListCellTitle" data-property-name="Revision Name" data-width="100%-80" data-id="SR::N::Ase0FunctionalElement..Fnd0FunctionalBOMLine..5.p5GBuC9OPIXzYA.H$CTuyM_PI3MLC.Group:/Thid_gndVeD_Jqd$DyB,,AWBCB" onclick="onEditLabelClicked(this)" ontouchstart="onEditLabelClicked(this)">Parent</text>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use "Copy CSS path" option by right click on element in chrome browser.

Comment: I tried that solution mentioned by @drkthng but its not working.Is there any other Solution?

Comment: what did not work? any error messages? is the snippet inside another frame or something? pls provide more information or more context about your page

Comment: getting null value.Is it problem with selenium webdriver?

Comment: can be. best you put (part of) your code in your question, then we can further analyze the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your code but the element that you want has an ID... did you try getting the element by ID?

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("title")).getText().trim());
```

If that doesn't work and you really want a CSS selector, try this one...

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("text[data-property-name='Revision Name']")));
```

The problem is that there are a LOT of CSS selectors that could be made for that element. We need more info on what is unique about it vs the others on the page.

Take a look at this [CSS Selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) and see if you can find one that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, unfortunately, this is not possible in CSS for the "text"-tag-element you are using.

See for example [this article](http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/01/css-selecting-text-nodes-as-with-xpath-text/):

> So if you feel you need to match text, you’ll have to use XPath
> instead (or put more classes and ids on your elements, so you can
> match against those).

## But

Just in case you do not need CSS locators unconditionally, then

one other possibility is xpath:

You will search for a "text" element whos text-node equals "Parent"

```
//text[text()='Parent']
```

Using for example Java you would get the element then this way:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//text[text()='Parent']"));
```